# Quick and simultaneous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am currently working on add sale for POS using laravel. Here we can use barcode to scan the product code, when barcode is entered it then calls check function, if same product code is found in the cart table then it simply adds the quantity value by 1 else it make an ajax call  which will return the detail of that particular product. My jQuery function looks like this:

```
 function check() {
     if ($(".product_code").length) {
         var product_code = $("#product_code").val();
         var total = $('#cart_contents tr').length;
         $('#cart_contents tr').each(function(index) {
             var p_code = $(this).find(".product_code").val();
             if (product_code == p_code) {
                 var num = +$(this).find('.product_quantity').val() + 1;
                 $(this).find('.product_discount').val(0);
                 $(this).find('.product_quantity').val(num).keyup();
                 return false;
             } else if (index === total - 1) {
                 populatecart();
             }
         });
     } else {
         populatecart();
         $(".cart_content_area").hide();
     }
 }

 function populatecart() {
     var product_code = $("#product_code").val();
     $.ajax({
         url: "{{ url('getproductdata')}}",
         data: {
             p_id: product_code
         },
         datatype: "JSON",
         type: "get",
         success: function(data) {
             if (data == 'null') {
                 alert('No product code found!');
             } else {
                 $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                    $("#cart_contents").append('<tr>' +
                        '<td class="quantity"> {!! Form::text('sales_quantity[]', 1, ['class'=>'product_quantity form-control']) !!} </td>' +
                        '<td class="product_codes"><input type="text" name="product_code[]" value="' + v["product_code"] + '" class="form-control product_code" readonly/></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" value="' + v["product_name"] + '" class="form-control product_name" readonly/> </td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" name="unit_value[]" value="' + v["sell_price"] + '" class="form-control unit_value" readonly/></td>' +
                        '<td>{!! Form::text('product_discount[]', 0, ['class'=>'product_discount form-control']) !!}</td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" name="line_total[]" value="' + v["sell_price"] + '" class="form-control line_total" readonly/></td>' +
                        '<td class="remove_row"><input name="product_id[]" type="hidden" value="' + v["id"] + '" /><button type="button" class="removebutton" title="Remove this row">X</button></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                     calculateTotalSum();
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

However, the problem here is that when I try to scan same product(ie; product having same product code) simultaneously it adds up the quantity but if i try the same thing really quick, the same product is populated into two different rows of the cart table but what I actually want is to have the quantity value of the product be 2 instead of creating 2 rows for same product code.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: I assume the scanner is writing the scanned barcode to the field `#product_code` before calling `check()`? Also what is `calculateTotalSum()` - you've not shown it - what does it do?

Comment: calculateTotalSum() is for calculating total cost of rows in cart table

Answer (score 2):

rather than use callback based api.
I suggest you use promise based .
the flow goes like this.

```
var cart = {};
if(cart[product_code] == undefined)
{
    cart[product_code] = $.ajax(url: "{{ url('getproductdata')}}"  , 
                      data:{
                            p_id:product_code
                            },
                      datatype:"JSON",
                      type: "get");
    cart[product_code].done(function(data){
      //do the initialization
    });
}
else
{
   cart[product_code].done(function(){
       //do the update.
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The ajax calls may overlap.

You should probably do the check for existance in the ajax callback only, not already in check();